# How does Beanstalkd manage memory?

Tags: php, macos, beanstalkd

We've just begun using `beanstalkd` in production, and are impressed with it's performance.

I've noticed that it does something peculiar with it's memory management. For instance, I create 100k jobs in PHP with `1111.013122,1212.121311` as data in each job. The memory usage of `beanstalkd` process goes up to `18MB` from about `300KB`. After a few minutes, the memory goes down to about `1.5MB`, with the same number of jobs still there.

Beanstalkd *not* running in persistent mode either.

I'm on a Mac, btw though our servers run Ubuntu 12.04. I've observed this on the Mac - haven't tried it on our servers yet.

Is this because of memory compression on the Mac or from Beanstalkd or is Beanstalkd writing out to a file? This would help us plan the memory requirement of our Queue servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beanstalkd is an in-memory queue, it uses external files only for error recovery (it can checkpoint jobs to a binlog, to recover in case of a crash).  So if the jobs haven't been deleted, they're still there in memory.

How are you measuring memory use?  Does the beanstalkd process virtual size shrink too?  Could the contents have been paged out to disk, thus no longer show up as resident? (or under "physical memory used"?)

Comment: They had been paged out, we didn't notice that earlier. Thanks!